# CSS background image on hover / active menu shrank

Tags: css, menu, background, hover

I have a menu like this:

```
<div id="header">
 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/home/"><img src="/images/icons/home.png" alt="Home" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/tool/"><img src="/images/icons/tool.png" alt="Tool" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/lists/"><img src="/images/icons/tags.png" alt="Lists" /></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like a **rectangle image on hover / active state**. The problem is that no matter what size my images are, they always shrank.

**My icons are 30px x 30px. My background images are 69px x 34px** (they squeeze almost 30x30).

These are my CSS:

```
#header {
    color      : #cccccc;
    font-size  : 1.0em;
    padding    : 0;
    min-height : 37px;
    background : #2d2d2d;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav {
    font-size      : 1.1em;
    display        : inline;
}

#nav ul {
    padding        : 0;
    margin-left    : 270px;
    margin-bottom  : auto;
    margin-top     : auto;
    float          : left;
    vertical-align : middle;
    list-style     : none;
    position       : relative;
    display        : inline-table;
    height         : 37px;
    line-height    : 37px;
}

#nav li {
    float           : left;
    list-style      : none;
    padding         : 0px 35px 3px 0px;
    display         : inline;
    vertical-align  : middle;
}

 #nav li img {
    top: 100%;
    vertical-align  : middle;
}


#nav a:hover {
    background: url('../images/icons/overtop.png') no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 69px 34px;
    width:69px;
    height:34px;
}

#nav a.active {
    background: url('../images/icons/backtop.png') no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    background-size: 100%; 
    background-size: 69px 34px;
    width:69px;
    height:34px;
}
```

Comment: Create a fiddle, I'll try it ;)

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/vizalizer/bhzrM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some things I did notice on first glance:

You should try using background-image:url('link/to/your/image.png').

You could also try omitting the background-size: 100% because it is redundant.

Just for clarification (I can't post comments due to my reputation being low) you are trying to indicate to the user what page they are currently on/about to click with a visual clue such as a black bar over the icon, correct?

***EDIT***

Try referencing the list items instead of the anchor tag on hover such as:

```
li:hover {
    background: url('http://216.119.77.64/test/icons/overtop.png')  no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    background-size: 69px 34px;
}
```

It fixes the size issue, but the images are not centered in the background.

Comment: I tried background-image, same result. I got rid of background-size, same. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, the wrapper div (<div id="header">) isn't closed from the code you posted.

Comment: True, is a copy paste issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try like this :

```
#nav a {
    border: 0;
    width:69px;
    height:34px;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background: url('../images/icons/overtop.png') no-repeat;
}

#nav a:active {
    background: url('../images/icons/backtop.png') no-repeat;
}
```